# Mathematica is getting slow when repeatedly calling an external program

Tags: performance-tuning, external-calls

I found a strange phenomenon that Mathematica is getting slow when I repeatedly called an external program by using ReadList. For example, the following code will display a significant increase of CPU time for each 'ls' command (my platform is OS X):

```
data = Table[Timing[ReadList["!ls"]], {100000}][[All, 1]];
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

This phenomenon seems ubiquitous for the other external programs. Can anyone suggest me how to avoid this speed down?

Comment: Is this actually a problem or just an annoyance?  When you say other external programs do you include ones with more significant IO than a simple ls?  Additionally does it do the same if you call ls through a shell script?  Ie are you sure it's MMA and not just OSX?

Comment: Gordon, thank you for your comment. Actually I need to run an external program (samtools, which is a popular genome analysis program) to get its output as a list. The point is that I have to call the program thousands of times in one session. The first call took 2 sec but the 1,000th call took almost 30 min due to the gradual seed down. It is strange because each call generates an independent process and it terminates before the next call. I used 'ls' command just to confirm the problem wasn't caused by samtools. I'd be very happy If you give me any further suggestions.

Comment: Confirmed same issue on my MBA running Mavericks and MMA10.1.  One point to note is my results for same code are 10 times faster i.e. 0.002 to 0.006 although the trend is very similar.  This may just be due to directory contents, or maybe my SSD?

Comment: Might be a good idea to send a bug report to WRI and see what they have to say about it.

Comment: I had to change the code to the following: `data = Table[Timing[Do[ReadList["!dir", "String"], {250}]], {100}][[All, 1]]; ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]`. However, with this I could not reproduce your observations on Windows. The timings appeared scattered in an essentially random way.

Comment: Perhaps some stream or channel is not being closed properly with this code under OS X?

Comment: I tried with alternative approaches, `RunProcess` and `Import`, not only they are slower but the loop crash before the 10000 iterations ...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Since I've been struggling with this problem for a week, they are really helpful. I noticed that the speed down is "continuous"even after an evaluation is finished: i.e., the degeneration of the performance is inherited to the next evaluation. I had to shutdown the Math kernel to reset the performance. This seems to suggest that there is a stream or channel problem relating to OS X as Mr.Wizard suggested. I feel I should contact WRI to report this issue as Pickett recommended.

Comment: It seems to me that it is not actually problem with calling external problems, but with importing data. For instance this code which calls external programs and put output in file shows no such problem `data2a = Table[Timing[Run["ls >> ls" <> ToString[i] <> ".dat"]], {i, 1000}][[All,1]];
ListPlot[data2a]`. On the other hand importing this data `data2b = Table[
   Timing[Import["ls" <> ToString[i] <> ".dat"]], {i, 1000}][[All, 
   1]]; ListPlot[data2b]` shows unwanted behavior!

Comment: Thanks. To use Run seems the best way to avoid the problem at present. I'm going to try it. I've reported WRI about the problem (potentially) caused by ReadList. I hope they'll give me a good solution.

Comment: OP, could you inform us if you had some sort of feedback? I would be very interested in answer to this question!